# How to get all characters after certain characters in a string sql

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

I have a column that contains rows with strings in the following form:

```
#S6TF3.01,#S6TF3.09,#S6TF3.10,#S6TF3.13
```

I want to be able to get the following result for all rows:

```
01,09,10,13
```

I am using tsql and have tried the following:

```
SUBSTRING(E.REJECT_WF_NOS, CHARINDEX('.', E.REJECT_WF_NOS) + 1, LEN(E.REJECT_WF_NOS))
```

Comment: The database is not so good if it is structured in this way...

Comment: If there is always 2 numbers behind the decimal, i would use string_split in 2016, to split by comma, then reverse your row and substring 2 and then reverse it back :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably split these out since the structure isn't constant. You seemingly only want the values after the decimal. This splits the value on the comma, then gets everything after the decimal, then re-concats it into a string.

**[ONLINE DEMO](http://rextester.com/TEUA13630)**

```
declare @var varchar(64) = 'S6TF3.01,#S6TF3.09,#S6TF3.10,#S6TF3.13'

SELECT
    STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + substring(item,charindex('.',Item) + 1,32)
          FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@var,',')
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

**[Here Is the Function from Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

/* "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)*/

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
GO
```

Comment: Well done. I'd change that nvarchar(max) to varchar(64) however. That value > datatype defines the data type of your output string which means you'll be  returning a nvarchar(max) when varchar(64) would do. AND the conversion will implicit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple 2016 version if you want it rowbased

```
select reverse(substring(reverse(value),1,2)),* from 
string_split('#S6TF3.01,#S6TF3.09,#S6TF3.10,#S6TF3.13',',')
```

**Result multiple rows - 2016:**

[image]**

If you want it in one row only, this could be the 2016 way

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
ID int ,
Strings varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable (ID,Strings)
select 1,reverse(substring(reverse(value),1,2)) as SplittedValues
from string_split('#S6TF3.01,#S6TF3.09,#S6TF3.10,#S6TF3.13',',')

---Select * from @MyTable

SELECT ID, NewVales = STUFF((SELECT N', ' + Strings 
FROM @MyTable AS p2
WHERE p2.ID = p.ID 
ORDER BY Strings
FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, N'')
FROM @MyTable AS p
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

**Result 1 row - 2016**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this you don't even need a splitter; you could use parsename to "split" the values.

```
declare @string varchar(100) = '#S6TF3.01,#S6TF3.09,#S6TF3.10,#S6TF3.13';

select newString = stuff
(( select ','+substring(item, 1, charindex(',', item)-1)
   from (values (4),(3),(2),(1)) t(n)
   cross apply (values (substring(@string, charindex('.',@string)+1, 8000)+',')) s(string)
   cross apply (values (parsename(string,n))) split(item)
   for xml path('')), 1,1,'');
```

This will be faster than delimitedsplit8k and does not require SQL Server 2016. On SQL Server 2017 you could simplify further like this:

```
select string_agg(substring(item, 1, charindex(',', item)-1),',')
from (values (4),(3),(2),(1)) t(n)
cross apply (values (substring(@string, charindex('.',@string)+1, 8000)+',')) s(string)
cross apply (values (parsename(string,n))) split(item)
```

Comment: Just a note, that function doesn't require SQL Server 2016   I like parsename though IF there aren't more than 4 values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data like row by row like as below Table Structure :

```
ID  DATA
1   #S6TF3.01
2   #S6TF3.09
3   #S6TF3.10
4   #S6TF3.13
```

And if you have always data like as above then just write the **substring** function as below :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DATA, 8, 2) DATA from #TEMP
```

Result:

```
ID  DATA       Result
1   #S6TF3.01   01
2   #S6TF3.09   09
3   #S6TF3.10   10
4   #S6TF3.13   13
```